# PHP Simple HTML DOM - stepping through a page

Tags: php, dom

I have been using the simple HTML DOM for some time, and have been loving what I can do with it. However I have run into a brick wall with something I would like to do.  First to give a basic idea of what the html looks like

```
<html>
<div><div><table><tr><td class="alt2"> texty texty </td></tr></table></div></div>
Text text
<div><div><table><tr><td class="alt2"> texty2 texty2 </td></tr></table></div></div>
Text2 text2
<div><div><table><tr><td class="alt2"> texty3 texty3 </td></tr></table></div></div>
Text2 text3
</html>
```

so basicly I need to take whats in the TD's bold that, and then place whats under each of this div under that.

so I know i can just do  $text = $html->find('td[class=alt2]') for example to get the to get "texty texty" but how to I associate "text text" with that after,

If I grab texty2 texty2, how do I associate text2 text 2 with that?

---

in the end, the output I was aiming for was `<p>texty texty</p><br>text text`  kind of thing

I should point out that the divs can have differnt classes and such, so simple reg expressions wouldnt work (and would like to stick with simple html dom if possible)

--

UPDATE:

I have made this little bit of code

```
if ($html) {


// Pulls the div that holds the links to the champion profiles (where they have the english names)
$text = $html->find('td[class="alt2"]');
$count = 0;
foreach ($text as $holder) {

    $tdholder[] = $holder->innertext;
    $html->find('div',$count*2)->innertext = $holder->innertext;
    echo $holder."<br><br>";
    $count++;
}
}
```

the only issue with this code, is it counts by the total number of divs. this is okay in my exmaple, as there are always 2. but if there are 2 or three, this makes an issue.  So now I just need to figure out how to grab just the first, or the second, or the third top level divs and I should be good.

Comment: one solution im thinking of while waiting, is looping through once to grab each of the TD's contents, then looping through again, and changing then simply telling to to replace the first top level div with the contents of the first td... going to work on that now

Comment: `Text text` , `Text2 text2`  and `Text2 text3` is not in any html tag which makes your request ambiguous

Comment: @Baba thats the issue. If they were in a tag, I could just match them up via an array.

Answer (score 0):

`Text text` , `Text2 text2`  and `Text2 text3` is not in any html tag which makes your request ambiguous

The solution below would work `but it is code specific` it would only work for the HTML example above add your original HTML for better implementation

```
$list = array();
foreach ( $html->find('text') as $td ) {
    $list[] = $td->plaintext;
}

echo "<pre>";   
foreach (array_chunk(array_filter(array_map("trim", $list)), 2) as $info ) {
    vprintf("TD: %s,\tTXT: %s \n", $info);
}
```

Output

```
TD: texty texty,    TXT: Text text 
TD: texty2 texty2,  TXT: Text2 text2 
TD: texty3 texty3,  TXT: Text2 text3
```

Comment: I programed something that will work, the only issue is it works with just 2 divs per table.  I need to find a way to grab the first top level div, and then the "Second" top level div (not the second div on the page, which is why my code does (or did)

`if ($html) {
 

// Pulls the div that holds the links to the champion profiles (where they have the english names)
$text = $html->find('td[class="alt2"]');
$count = 0;
foreach ($text as $holder) {
 
 $tdholder[] = $holder->innertext;
 $html->find('div',$count*2)->innertext = $holder->innertext;
 echo $holder."<br><br>";
 $count++;
}
}`

Comment: Am working blind here my first tag is `html` followed by `div` .... there is not much i can do with the information you have provided

Comment: the info I gave is all there really is. the text and such is dynamic. but the layout will always be the TD with the alt2 class, inside 2 or more divs, followed by the text under it (that is inside no tag) the code i wrote there (and also updated to my first post) solves the issue. However, it only solves it if there will always be 2 divs.   However, this can be fixed if I can just figure out how to get an array of only the TOP level divs.